# CLGeocoder alternative to geocode large number of coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, clgeocoder

I am wanting to geocode a large number of coordinates, sometimes hundreds. I would love to pass an `NSArray` to `CLGeocoder`, but the docs say that you should only make one request per minute.

**Is there any other service that allows a larger number of geocodes?**

Comment: This says it'll handle up to 100 per request. Haven't used it, though. http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/

Comment: @AdrianB - Looks like they only provide 15,000 request per month for free.